# gem install sassc fails

Tags: sass, rubygems

I am trying to install sassc
but building the native extensions fails:

```
$ gem install sassc
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sassc:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /data/hermes/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sassc-2.2.1/ext
/data/hermes/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/bin/ruby -I /data/hermes/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r 
./siteconf20200114-2123-fk2nkv.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /data/hermes/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sassc-2.2.1/ext
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /data/hermes/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sassc-2.2.1/ext
make "DESTDIR="
compiling ./libsass/src/cencode.c
compiling ./libsass/src/c99func.c
compiling ./libsass/src/environment.cpp
In file included from ./libsass/src/environment.cpp:1:0:
./libsass/src/sass.hpp:55:18: fatal error: string: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [environment.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in 
/data/hermes/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sassc-2.2.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /data/hermes/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64- 
linux/2.7.0/sassc-2.2.1/gem_make.out
```

Obviously the compiler cannot resolve #include .

My environment is:

```
$ gem --version
3.1.2

$ ruby --version
ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-linux]

$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 5.2.0

$ uname -a
Linux m4sxvmvsm6h4 2.6.32-696.20.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 12 15:07:59 EST 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

I have problems with **sassc** version **2.2.1** too, but version **2.1.0** does not have some exceptions.

In `Gemfile`, try to add **sassc** with version **2.1.0**

```
gem 'sassc', '~> 2.1.0'
```

and then in terminal, run:

```
bundle update sassc
```

to update `Gemfile.lock`
and run again:

```
bundle
```